# How to use cloudbees jenkins license for different instance ID

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees

I have a cloudbees license and I am trying to upgrade my 1x Jenkins to 2x.

But when I used license of 1x for 2x cloudbees Jenkins it says:

```
the Jenkins server id is different adfhfjxxxxxx 
please use licences for server id xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there any way I can use same license for different Jenkins server ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading "[Jenkins Enterprise License Activation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218233918-Jenkins-Enterprise-License-Activation) ", you could:

- request and use an evaluation license for the Jenkins 2.x you are testing,
- while opening a support ticket and enter your Jenkins instance ID current, along with your name and company name, explaining the situation: the support should get back to you with a new license.

Comment: But I have complete license for cloudbees Jenkins 1x. Do I need to request license for different Jenkins instances? and also for upgrading from 1x to 2x requires new license? @Vonc

Comment: @pandey those are the questions the support will answer directly: don't forget to mention if the server itself changes or if you are running the new Jenkins on the same server.